# Booting USB/ I just can't get it to work

Tags: windows, boot, usb, bios

So, 
I've got this laptop, and it won't start up. when ever you turn on the power it keeps loading

[I'v even left it on for a day it ust wont start up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2lGz.jpg)

i"ve even tried all standard recovery options but that doesn't work either

So next step i tought Let's reinstall windows.
So i made a bootable USB drive. But in BIOS I can't select USB 
[Where did it go?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsI95.jpg)

So after I Googled i found out I had to disable secure boot but i don't have that option. i read i had to update my BIOS, but i can't start up the laptop. i've tried diffrent USB ports i've even tried a SD card. and tried a bunch of other things and seen a couple of things that are not possible in my BIOS

And than i read about Launching EFI Shell (never heard from it before)
and i saw the option in my BIOS. i tought maybe if i could launch that and than boot the USB from there it might work.
But i cant get it to launch either. It gives a warning "Not Found"

What do i try next?

Comment: The motherboard firmware laptops used to have were called BIOS, but are now called UEFI which looks the same and some still mistakenly call BIOS (that's a point re terminology). You could state your laptop make in the question as sometimes there can be people that know about specific laptops. And different laptops can have different UEFIs. You should also include some information about the UEFI..

Answer (score -1):

I would try booting it to safe mode.
Start the Laptop as you would do normally and press and hold F8 while waiting for the windows logo to appear. You should be getting to a very basic part of windows, where you can choose whether you want to start it from safe mode (if needed with certain drivers), a different monitor resolution etc.
Try out the normal Safe mode.

If your BIOS cannot find your USB, you might want to plug your USB to a different USB-Port. I had the same thing when I wanted to flash my BIOS and it did not get recognized on different ports I tried. Test them all out unless you have already did.

Comment: -1 You wrote "press and hold F8 while waiting for the windows logo to appear.You should be getting to a BIOS looking program, where you can choose whether you want to start it from safe mode" <---  Pressing F8 does not lead to anything like the BIOS (or the UEFI). To say so is SO misleading

Comment: And you write "If you cannot find your USB, you might want to change the USB-Port..... you might want to change the USB-Port." <-- You mean If IT/(the computer) cannot find/(detect) the USB, you might want to change the USB-port(/i.e. plug the USB into a different USB port).   (To say change the USB port suggests changing a setting, and you don't mean that there). Your statements and 'substatements' are ambiguous.

Comment: @barlop I like the way "first ask and then beat" more, but if you have to downvote before suggesting an edit, you shall do so. However I changed those "mistakes" now. Btw with "BIOS looking" I never mentioned anything hanging together with the functionality, just the look (usually black background with white letters, where you can steer with the keyboard only).

Comment: DOS and even CMD has black background and white letters. It's confusing and unnecessary and even misleading, to say it's like a BIOS. I understand you didn't mean it is a BIOS. It's just a horrible comparison to be making.  I said it's "SO Misleading"  I didn't say it was wrong, as I saw you weren't technically saying it was a/the BIOS.  And even what you just said is misleading about black background and white letters.. as it's so often not true of a BIOS(they're most often blue or grey background), and DOS and cmd can have different colours.

Comment: And since you parallel the colours in your last comment.. to say BIOSs have white text on black background, can you name me two BIOSs (or UEFIs) that have white text on a black background?  If any, it's a tiny number. I doubt you can even name two (though even if you can it's a rarity). I've looked through a bunch on google images and can't see any that match what you said as if the norm.